# How to put html tag inside html tag in jsp page

Tags: java, html, jsp

In my website, I download a full webpage from another site, modify something and extract it as a string. Now, I want to display it as a part of my `.jsp` page, with scrolling bar.

How can I do that? It shows me error when I try to put another `<html>` tag.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT!!!**

Here is my `.jsp`

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Create Your XSLT Here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="../AdminServlet">
            URL <input type="text" name="txtUrl" value="" /><br/>
            Start Promotion <input type="text" name="txtStart" value="" /><br/>
            Produt Name <input type="text" name="txtProductName" value="" /><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="View" name="action" />
        </form>
        <c:if test="${not empty requestScope.website}">
            <div>
                ${requestScope.website}
            </div>
        </c:if>
    </body>
</html>
```

`requestScope.website` is a full html page as a string, return from server. When I run, everything in the `requestScope.website` (such as background image) apply to all my page. I want to limit it to a part of my page, just like using `iframe`.

Comment: Show your tried code.

Comment: look into iframes. They are used exactly for this.

Comment: I use iframe when I have a link. But now, I have a full source webpage.

Comment: Just insert the contents of the body element, not the whole HTML.

Comment: I have to insert all because of the CSS. If I insert the body only, no CSS applied.

Comment: have you tried using `JSP include` library ?

Answer (score 0):

I think u can use the `<jsp:include ...>`tag.
Put the whole source code into a jsp and use the tag to include to your page.

Something like

```
<jsp:include page="mypagepath/page.jsp"></jsp:include>
```